# Should the first paragraph after a chapter be indented if it is quoted dialogue?

Tags: formatting

In my manuscript I generally do not indent the first paragraph following a chapter heading. This generally looks good and reads well with the exception of starting a chapter with quoted dialogue. See examples below.

---

### Example 01:

[image]

---

### Example 02:

[image]

---

The second option just looks wrong to me. Are there any official guidelines or best practices for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it consistent. If you are using indented paragraphs with the first paragraph of a chapter not indented, maintain this regardless of the content. Starting with quoted speech isn’t a reason to break consistency.

This formatting style is very common, and chapters that start with quoted text are always formatted the same as regular text: with no indent.